# Recommended IRC server (ircd) for a small site?

Tags: linux, comparison, irc

The situation:

I want to play around with IRC bots as general communications interfaces to other code I am investigating.  The server hardware would be old and low-memory, but running on a relatively up-to-date Debian GNU/Linux install.  I don't expect more than a hundred users at a time, tops, and probably in the single-digits most of the time.  The interfaces are more of interest here than the server itself, so I'd prefer something relatively simple to maintain over something with a huge number of configuration and tuning options more useful to a larger site.

Referencing the [Wikipedia comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_IRC_daemons) and the [Google PageRank list](http://www.google.com/Top/Computers/Software/Internet/Servers/Chat/IRC/) against the available package list for Debian comes up with the following top contenders: [Undernet](http://coder-com.undernet.org/) (ircd-ircu), [Ratbox](http://www.ircd-ratbox.org/) (ircd-ratbox), and [Inspire](http://www.inspircd.org/) (inspircd).  Unfortunately, I can't find any serious comparisons of them, so I'm hoping that asking here will provide a faster solution than just trying them one at a time until something frustrates me enough to move.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

During the past couple days I have been coding a bot with Python and IRCLib. Since I am coding the communication interface I needed to see the raw data transfered between the server and the client. So, I needed an IRC server which would support that. At first I was using IRCD, and it was totally fine. But after a while I realized that I was missing some features that IRCD did not have since it's outdated. So, after further research I found ngIRCd.

I compiled it from source with those options "--enable-sniffer --enable-debug". Now when I want to see the information sent between my bot and my client I only need to start the server with the -n and -s option. Like that : ngircd -n -s

Here is the website of the server : http://ngircd.barton.de/

Answer (score 9):

[Unreal IRCd](http://www.unrealircd.com/) is full featured if a little complex on the setup.

Comment: The groups I've chatted with always seemed to use Unreal.

Comment: I second Unreal as it's very feature-rich. I don't know how it scales or how secure it is, but it sounds like he won't have any of those issues anyway. My second vote [or true first] would go to ratbox.

Comment: Thanks, Till.  Can you say more about why you would go with ratbox? There's no package for Unreal on Debian, so I'd have to roll my own for that (which I can do, but it's extra work), and I'm not enthusiastic about the 'complex on the setup' part, either.

Answer (score 2):

Unreal IRCd is what I finally picked for hosting an IRCD.  Why?  Halfop, admin/protect, founder/owner, advanced operator acl, vHost via i:line and etc...

Also see

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_IRC_daemons
- http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_irc_server_anope_services

Answer (score 1):

Use XMPP instead.  IRC is not very well designed for your situation; it can be made to work, but it is a big pain.

Comment: http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/xml/xmpp/